# Add Task in Default Reminder App From iOS App

Tags: ios

How to add Task in Reminder Default app from iOS mine developed app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access Reminders in iOS apps using APIs in `EventKit.framework`, in iOS 6 or later. See these links to the official iOS documentation:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingReminders/ReadingAndWritingReminders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH5-SW1
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/EKEventStore

Comment: I had referred that document but I tried that but it is not working as actual and Can't understand properly can you please send me the actual code on stackoverflow